Inadequate highlighting in code's output cells in an IPython notebook in VSCode
I am using VSCode to edit and run my IPython notebooks.
Upon using them, I wanted to preserve the coloring of some magic commands like !grep when I used them. Thanks to this question here on SE, I have found out that I could simply put !grep --color=always [PATTERN] [FILE] in a code cell, so that the output preserves highlighting that grep produces when used in the terminal. However, when I tried to use it like this in VSCode, appropriate highlighting seems to have went off for some reason: [Click here to see the VSCode's highlighting]
However, when I open the very same file in a Jupyter environment, highlighting seems to be just fine: [Click here to see the Jupyter's highlighting]
What could be the reason for VSCode's highlighting to turn inadequate and is there any way to fix it?
I am using VSCode 1.94.2, IPython 8.20.0, and WSL on Ubuntu 22.04 lts.
Thanks in advance for your help!

A small note: in the picture that shows Jupyter notebook's highlighting the --color flag in grep is set to auto. This flag setting doesn't actually change how the output is highlighted in VSCode.

Looks like the VSCode printed all the characters after the matching block red.Maybe you could submit an issue to the GitHub so it can be fixed.https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter
